# Unfortunately myApp has stopped in emulator

Tags: java, android, eclipse, emulation

My android project does not show any errors in the console, however, when I try to run the app. It opens my first page however does not open the next page when clicked on the button.
Below is my code:

```
    package com.example.nearestparks;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Information extends Activity {

    ListView list;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_information);
        list=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        list.setAdapter(new TinuAdapter(this));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.information, menu);
        return true;
    }

}

class SingleRow
{
    String title;
    String description;
    int image;

    SingleRow(String title,String descriptions,int image)
    {
        this.title=title;
        this.description=description;
        this.image=image;
    }

}


class TinuAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{

    ArrayList<SingleRow> list;
    Context context;
    TinuAdapter(Context c)
    {
        context=c;
        list=new ArrayList<SingleRow>();
        Resources res=c.getResources();
        String [] titles=res.getStringArray(R.array.titles);
        String [] descriptions=res.getStringArray(R.array.descriptions);
        int[] images={R.drawable.icon_park};
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            list.add(new SingleRow (titles[i],descriptions[i],images[i]));
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row =inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row,viewGroup,false);

        TextView title=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView description=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        ImageView image =(ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        SingleRow temp = list.get(i);

        title.setText(temp.title);
        description.setText(temp.description);
        image.setImageResource(temp.image);




        return row;
    }




}
```

The error on logcat show java.lang.Array.OutOfBounds.Exception: length =0; inde

Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: How do you know `titles`, `descriptions` and `images` all contain 5 items?

Answer (score 0):

`int[] images={R.drawable.icon_park};`

images is a one item array, but below you loop it 5 times

`list.add(new SingleRow (titles[i],descriptions[i],images[i]));`

So after the first loop iteration images[1] will fail.